# How do you shift an image up by 50 pixels in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, pixel

I would like to shift an image up by 50 pixels, leaving the remaining bottom pixels all white.
There are 128 pixels in each row (the width of the image in terms of the number of pixels), and there are 128 rows (the height of the image in terms of the number of pixels), and each colour of each pixel is represented by an 8-bit number (has maximum value of 255). The header information part altogether is 61 bytes long
Below is the MIPS code.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
.data
input_file_name: .asciiz "in.ppm"
output_file_name: .asciiz "out.ppm"

.text
main:
# Open the input file for reading the image from:
li   $v0, 13       # system call for open file
la   $a0, input_file_name      # input file name
li   $a1, 0        # flag for reading
li   $a2, 0        # mode is ignored
syscall            # open a file
addu $s0, $zero, $v0      # save the file descriptor

addi $t0, $zero, 1
sll  $t0, $t0, 7
sll  $t0, $t0, 7
addu $t1, $t0, $t0
addu $t0, $t1, $t0
addi $s1, $t0, 61
sub $s2, $sp, $s1

# s1: size of the image in bytes
# s2: address of the starting byte of the buffer for the image

# Reading from file just opened
li   $v0, 14       # system call for reading from file
addu $a0, $zero, $s0      # file descriptor
addu $a1, $zero, $s2   # address of buffer to read to
addu $a2, $zero, $s1  # how many bytes to read
syscall            # read from file

# Close the input file:
li $v0, 16         # system call code for close file
addu $a0, $zero, $s0      # file descriptor to close
syscall            # close file


# s2: still holds the address of the starting byte of the buffer for the image

# >>>>>>>> MAKE YOUR CHANGES BELOW THIS LINE

addiu    $t0, $s2, 61

li  $s3, 3 # colours
li  $s4, 128 # columns
li  $s5, 128 # rows

li      $t4, 0 # row counter
Loop_over_rows:
li      $t3, 0 # column counter
Loop_over_pixels_in_each_row: # i.e., columns
li      $t2, 0 # colour counter (each colour represents Red-Green-Blue)
Loop_over_colours_in_each_pixel:
lb      $t1, 0($t0) # loading the value of the byte, representing the intensity of the corresponding RGB colour of that pixel
# Do something with the value of the byte
sb      $t1, 0($t0) #
addi    $t0, $t0, 1 # address of the next byte
addi    $t2, $t2, 1 # counter of the colour bytes for each pixel
bne     $t2, $s3, Loop_over_colours_in_each_pixel
addi    $t3, $t3, 1 # counter over the pixels in a row (column)
bne     $t3, $s4, Loop_over_pixels_in_each_row
addi    $t4, $t4, 1
bne     $t4, $s5, Loop_over_rows

# <<<<<<<< MAKE YOUR CHANGES ABOVE THIS LINE

# Open a file for saving the processed image to:
li $v0, 13 # system call for open file
la $a0, output_file_name # input file name
li $a1, 0x41 # flag for writing
li $a2, 0x1B4 # mode is ignored
syscall # open a file
addu $s0, $zero, $v0 # save the file descriptor

# Saving the processed image to it:
li $v0, 15
addu $a0, $zero, $s0
addu $a1, $zero, $s2
addu $a2, $zero, $s1
syscall

# Close the output file:
li $v0, 16 # system call code for close file
syscall # close file

# Finish the programme:
li $v0, 10 # syscall code for exit
syscall # exit
```

Comment: The homework-style problem statement is good context, but at this website, you have to have a technical question, so we know what you need to know or what you've tried, and where you're stuck.  We don't offer solutions to problems here, only answers to questions that are intended to enlighten readers to get past where they're stuck.

Comment: FYI, a pixel is going to be 4 bytes wide, so you'll need to take that into account when dealing with byte addresses for shifting the image.

Comment: Looks like you need an algorithm.  An algorithm is language independent, so does not require "thinking in assembly".  I suggest trying to identify an algorithm in your head, or on paper first, or pseudo code, or in C.  Then you can take that algorithm to assembly code.

Comment: Try to think in terms of the effect you want on the data and how to accomplish that. One approach to algorithms is to make the problem smaller and solve that first, then expand it.  For example, what if there were only one row, and it has 4 pixels and you wanted to shift it to the left by 2 pixels.  So, let's say we have an image that is: 0:White, 1:Black, 2:Red, 3:Green.  Shifted left by 2 pixels, you want the same image locations to now look like this 0:Red, 1:Green, 2:White, 3:White.  What would do you need to do to first image to get the second?

Comment: You could copy memory (like `memmove`), or you could copy the PPM header to the right spot and make a `write_file` system call with a pointer to that location.  (So it can copy from the right spot in memory to a file.)